# jQuery Mobile and PhoneGap Performance problems

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm currently working on an PhoneGap and JQM project and the project is reasonable complete the only problem I am having is jQuery Mobile itself. It seems to make the app sluggish and slow. Transitions between pages are slow. Showing and Hiding animations are tragic etc... Are there any other alternatives to getting a reasonable nice UI experience using PhoneGap with out all these problems?

Comment: Okay here is a start to the solution!! The link below is amazing. I literally downloaded the code, wrapped it into PhoneGap 2.5.0 and its running so so smooth!! [Link](http://coenraets.org/blog/2013/03/hardware-accelerated-page-transitions-for-mobile-web-apps-phonegap-apps/) That being said I hope more people can contribute to this answer!!

Comment: Which version of JQM did you use and on what device? JQM transitions should be accelerated by default already. Also note that the technique described has no fallback - when transitions are not supported the page will not load (e.g. on Opera 12 on desktop and probably on Android 2.3).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Angular or Backbone with Bootstrap for getting a reasonable nice UI experience.